# Происхождение слова "мамонт"

Tags: этимология

Откуда взялось в русском языке слово "мамонт"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В языке якутов или эвенков, откуда, по мнению некоторых исследователей, заимствовано это слово, животное называлось *мамут*, что значит «живущее в земле». Слово *мамут* происходит от mamma «земля». Якуты и эвенки верили, что мамонт жил в земле, подобно кроту (это животное известно только в ископаемом состоянии, извлекается из-под земли). Другие объясняют слово *мамонт* через польск. mamona «чудище». (Из Этимологического словаря русского языка Цыганенко Г.П.)

Comment: mamma «земля». 

"Мать сыра земля" .Какая прелесть!

Answer (score 1):

Происхождение неясно.

Comment: Смысл было публиковать ответ, не несущий абсолютно ничего нового в плане ответа на вопрос?

Comment: @Arhad: судя по [**словарям Крылова, Фасмера и Шанского**](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82) происхождение действительно неясно. Хотя, конечно, лучше было бы дополнить ответ ссылками на авторитетные источники или хотя бы атрибутировать его. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Точный источник не устанавливается, но почти наверняка — из языков аборигенных народов сибири (якутский, ненецкий, тунгусский). Только таким происхождением можно объяснить отсутсвие генетических связей в индоевропейских и других контактных языках. Сближение с собственным именем Мамант, видимо, вторично.